# How can I redirect/route the alerts of Google Workspace to any 3rd party or any servers/VMs?

Tags: alerts, google-alert-center-api

I want to redirect the Google Workspace alerts with of our security team's tool SIEM/SPLUNK. I'm looking for a way to integrate Google Alerts.

I have tried a lot of ways and I have read a lot of articles but didn't find anything concrete. Google support suggested me to come here and ask for the suggestion. I am looking for any solution which can help me achieve my goal. Even if it's via an API.